# Unordered version of itertools.permutations

Tags: python

The following program constructs a URL from a list using the `itertools.permutations`.

```
def url_construct_function():
    for i in range(1, len(samplelist)):
        for item in list(permutations(samplelist, i)):
```

1. Suppose there are 3 items presented in the sample list: `a`,`b`,`c`
2. `itertools.permutations` provides a good description around various possible ordered combinations

   - a
   - b
   - c
   - a,b
   - a,c
   - b,a
   - b,c
   - c,a
   - c,b

I want to make the program understand that `a,b` and `b,a` are the same.

Comment: `itertools.combinations` instead of `permutations` maybe ...

Comment: @schwobaseggl, that looks like an asnwer

Comment: Phew , Thanks a lot!  @schwobaseggl    , I have been going crazy :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`itertools.combinations` works like `itertools.permutations` and does what you are looking for (and what the name suggests)

```
from itertools import combinations
...
    for item in list(combinations(samplelist, i)):
    ...
a
b
c
a, b
a, c
b, c
```

as in combinations, unlike permutations, order doesn't matter. All neatly covered in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement).